# MSVC 2010: Allow right-click menu in console during input

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

When I call `cin` or `getline` with cin in my Visual Studio 2010 C++ app, I can enter something in the console (as it should be), but the right-click context menu is "blocked". It doesn't appear - this means I and my clients are not able to use copy and paste.

- How to enable the context menu in the console with cin?

Answer (score 1):

This is an end user configuration for console windows.  Click on the title bar icon, select properties, on the options tab, uncheck QuickEdit mode.

However copy & past is in fact simpler in QuickEdit mode:  Right click performs an immediate paste operation if there is text in the clipboard.  Text is copied by highlighting by dragging over the text to be copied, and pressing "Enter" to place the text in the clipboard.  Switching off QuickEdit us useful for console programs that consume mouse events directly.

I am not sure that there is a programmatic method of switching the edit mode, but since it is by design an end user preference, it would probably be bad form to impose your own preference.

Comment: This is not my problem. A) QuickEdit mode was and is already turned off and B) I don't have the problems with other applications making use of the console

Comment: I have reproduced your problem and was too surprised since I have never noticed this behaviour.  It is not specific to cin however (the context meny is available even when not waiting for input), and only does this when running in the debugger.  Nonetheless the title-bar menu's Edit sub-menu menu still works, as does QuickEdit mode, so you should have at least two methods of copy & pasting data even during debug.

Comment: ... I just noticed that you used VC++2010.  I find it hard to believe that it would make a difference, but I tested it with VC++ 2008.

Comment: I'm using VS2008, but it's on top of Win7 x64. After compiling and running just a basic c++ app, I cannot use the context menu. However, if I start a console (cmd.exe) and then run the app from there, the context menu is present.

Comment: I *can* right-click the menu and under edit the copy/mark/paste functions appear. Still not sure how to get them to work when you click the black area. I'm guessing you'd have to trap for that and handle it.

Comment: @Skub: As I mentioned above, the feature appears to be disabled when the code is run in the debugger.  Running from cmd.exe or from the IDE's "Run without debugging" menu/button it should work.